# Arduino Ethernet Shield vs Eclipse (libraries problems)

Tags: eclipse, arduino

I try to use an Arduino Ethernet [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields). I checked Arduino IDE and the embedded examples with their libraries and they work fine.

I work with Eclipse. I copied the libraries to my project, and I get a specific error in general for some of the libraries.

The compiler does not recognize the equality of `unsigned char` and `uint8_t`.

So when it reads the libraries if the operant of a function should be `unit8_t` and it sees that, the library has an `unsigned char`, and it gives an error.

I could try to cast one by one, but is there a better more general solution?

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to add the below library, which defines the uint8_t and such a like.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
```

or add it to the path of Eclipse. It is included to the path of core libraries of the Arduino IDE.

Comment: i have tried that and i have also include the next headers inside one of the .cpp files in order to try find the correct that solves the problem."stddef.h" "inttypes.h""stdint.h" <string.h> <stdlib.h> "Dhcp.h""Arduino.h""util.h" "pgmspace.h"

Comment: well i do not know if i have to answer my question in order to give you feedback for your solution so i comment it.plz correct me if i should answer my question in order to give more details

Comment: also there is a type of folder named includes in the project that has inside the /application/arduino.app/..../avr/.../stddef.h and all the headers that i found it is needed. i tried to add these folders inside the properties---> directories that it uses but it does not recognize it as a folder of the workspace.SO i can see a "folder" in my project that is something like a link to the some headers but i can not include it in the project directories as lib directory.

Comment: so i tries as i said to copy them one buy one to find out which solves my problem. i told you which are the headers but none solves the problem. I tried to clean and rebuilt etc ...